# Change "View merge request for $branch" post push message in Gitlab

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-omnibus

Using a self hosted gitlab instance, how can I modify this message that I get after pushing to the repository, on my git client side ?

```
git push
[...]
remote: 
remote: View merge request for MYBRANCH:
remote:   https://GITLAB_MR.URL
remote:
```

I tried checking the server side hooks of my omnibus installation in

> /var/opt/gitlab/git-data/repositories/@hashed/MY_REPO_HASH

But I cant find any hook with this message there using `grep -Hrn "View merge request"`

Is this message not from a git hook ? How to configure it ?

If I cannot change it without modifying Gitlab's code, how can I add text there for pushers to read ?

Comment: The Git client side is unaware of the message contents: it's instructed to pass a message through (via a side channel from the server) and it does so, prefixing it with `remote:` and that's all there is on the client side. So this has to be done on the server side. Where you can do it (somewhere in the GitLab code) I don't know.

Comment: @torek Thanks for the information. Do you know if there is an other way to add text there without modifying gitlab's code ?

Comment: Well, whatever you're changing will be "GitLab's code" so by definition the answer is trivially "no", but it *might* be as simple as a shell / bash script that makes it really easy to *do*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out, this can only be done by modifying Gitlab's code and not by user configuration as of today.

I found the source of the message here : https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/blob/master/lib/gitlab/internal_post_receive/response.rb

Of course most users wouldn't find this solution pratical.